# Attempt to get length of null array when the app runs from Mobile Device

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to load some photos from the SQLite database into my app. Since I am using RecyclerView in my adapter class on this particular line where I am converting a byte array to the actual Image I am getting

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

but only when the app runs from my mobile. If I am using emulator everything runs perfectly
To convert a byte array to ImageView I use Bitmap:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        mImageIv.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

All my photos are saved as BLOB type and any of them isn't bigger than 50kb with resolution 500x500.

I have tried also to convert bytes using Picasso library but it didn't work either on emulator nor on my mobile.

Next solution was Glide that gives me perfect output on the emulator, but when I run the app from my phone it says that some of the tables don't exist and this is the error:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: WHITEWINE (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM WHITEWINE

Then I tried to run from another mobile device (older than my mobile), and this is where I got completely confused... Some of the tables with photos are loaded and placed in their fragments... But for the rest, if I try to open those fragments my app will crash, and the error will be this one:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(128261340bytes) bitmap.

Now I don't have an idea is it really a problem with memory because my photos are saved in BLOB type or it's something different?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my errors!

Regarding the first one:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

I am not using Bitmap anymore, instead, I implemented the Glide library! And this simple line of code solved my error:

```
Glide.with(mCtx).load(image).into(mImageIv);
```

Regarding the second error:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: WHITEWINE (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM WHITEWINE

Apparently I had a junk file in my "databases" folder in DDMS. I am still not getting how it was there since I had uninstalled my app several times in order to solve that problem. Anyway, I just deleted "databases" folder from DDMS and rerun the app... So now the second error is solved.

And finally regarding my third error which occurred on the older mobile device:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(128261340bytes) bitmap

This one was caused by the photos from my drawable folder... They were too big for the mobile device that has less memory. I was a bit lazy to resize them, so I just copied them to the drawable folder. The solution was by using an amazing app cold "Final Android Resizer" to resize my photos, and I got a perfect run on the older mobile devices.